# how to configure a mounted drive to not show up under devices

Tags: 13.10, mount, home-directory, fstab, devices

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a system with three separate drives. The `/` and swap are on the first (sda), `/home` is on the second (sdb), and I have `/home/*username*/Backup` on the third (sdc). I had this set up before on CrunchBang and they all three just showed as one device but for some reason on Ubuntu I can only get sda and sdb to show as one device and sdc shows as a separate device. I edited `/etc/fstab` and it mounts sda1 as `/`, sdb1 as `/home` and sdc1 as `/home/*username*/Backup`. I dont understand why sdc shows up as a separate device that I can eject in Ubuntu. Anyone have any answers?

Answer (score 1):

I changed `/dev/sdc1` in fstab to mount at `/home/Backup` and now all three drives appear as one device. Don't really understand why that changes anything but it works. If anyone knows why that makes the difference feel free to comment. Thanks.